# Excel listObject doesn't show updated values in worksheet.Change event

Tags: c#, excel, events, vsto, excel-2016

I have an excel table created programmatically, which uses a `List<Object>` as a data source. I am creating this table by adding a `ListObject` using Tools.Worksheet `AddListObject()`, and then assigning `listObject.DataSource` with `List<Object>`. Table is getting created and works fine and user can edit any cell/row in a table.

I am handling edits using the `WorkSheet.Change` event. When a user edits a cell which belongs to a table the `worksheet.Change` event is fired (Verified by setting a breakpoint in the Change event handler) as expected.

I am accessing the table/listObject using target sent to Change event handler then I am using `Factory.GetVstoObject(target.ListObject)` to get `Tools.ListObject`. Everything works fine till this point.

**Issue:**

When I access `ListObject.DataSource`, I see that the values in `dataSource` is **not** updated with new value. I need this new value in `workSheet.Change` event to do some validation and other stuff. Why am I not seeing updated values in Change event handler? DataSource values should be updated to new values before reaching `WorkSheet.Change` event handler right? Is there any way to fix this issue or Is there any other way to get new values of table/listObject?

PS: After change event handler is executed and say if User edits again, I see 1st edited value in `listObject.DataSource` (Not 2nd edit value). I tried `ListObject.Change` event as well, still seeing old value.

Here's the code : 
This is how I am creating a new worksheet.

```
public static Worksheet CreateNewExcelSheet(string sheetName)
{
    var newWorksheet = (Worksheet)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Worksheets.Add();
    newWorksheet.Name = sheetName;
    newWorksheet.Activate();
    newWorksheet.Change += WorkSheetChange_EventHandler;
    newWorksheet.CustomProperties.Add(IsTableSelected, "false");
    return newWorksheet;
}
```

Code for creating listobject:

```
public static Tools.ListObject CreateListObject(Worksheet workSheet, Range startingPosition, string listObjectName)
{
    var vstoWorkSheetObject = GetVstoWorkSheetObject(workSheet);
    var listObject = 
    vstoWorkSheetObject.Controls.AddListObject(startingPosition, listObjectName);
    listObject.Deselected += ListObject_Deselected;
    listObject.Selected += ListObjectOnSelected;
    listObject.Change += ListObject_Change;
    listObject.DataBindings.Clear();
    listObject.TableStyle = TableStyle;
    return listObject;
}
```

Main Code:

```
private void CreateTable(string sheetName, string listObjectName)
{
    var workSheet = CreateNewExcelSheet(sheetName);
    var listObject = CreateListObject(workSheet, Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Range["A4"], listObjectName);
    listObject.SetDataBinding(dataSourceFromServer);
    var counter = 0;
    foreach (Range cell in listObject.HeaderRowRange.Cells)
    {
        cell.Value2 = ColumnNames[counter];
        counter++;
    }
    listObject.HeaderRowRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
}
```

dataSourceFromServer is of type `List<Object>`

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: @JeroenHeier  Attached code to the question.