# How to trigger update in ListObject binding in Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have a `ListObject` bound to a `DataSet` as described in [How to: Add ListObject Controls to Worksheets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eyfs6478.aspx).  I would like to compute certain column values as each row is entered.

Example:

1. With a table defined for A1:D2, and the cursor in A2
2. Type a value in A2
3. Hit tab
4. Desired behavior: row is updated in dataset, I [can detect the change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rowchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and update other columns
   Actual behavior: row is not updated until the cursor enters another row

How to I cause the table to update the `DataSet` upon the current cell losing focus?

Comment: Possibly similar but different: [Excel listObject doesn't show updated values in worksheet.Change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44932539/excel-listobject-doesnt-show-updated-values-in-worksheet-change-event)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SheetTableUpdate` event to capture the change in the listobject.

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
{
    public static Excel.Application e_application;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        e_application = this.Application;
        e_application.SheetTableUpdate += new Excel.AppEvents_SheetTableUpdateEventHandler(e_Application_SheetTableUpdate_Event);
    }

    private void e_Application_SheetTableUpdate_Event(object sender, Excel.TableObject target)
    {
        //--sender object refers to active sheet and must be cast as Worksheet before use
        //Update your dataset here
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        e_application.SheetTableUpdate -= new Excel.AppEvents_SheetTableUpdateEventHandler(e_Application_SheetTableUpdate_Event);
        e_application = null;
    }

    protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
    {
        return new Ribbon();
    }
}
```

You can reference the `ActiveCell` by using the following bit of code.

```
(Excel.Range)Application.ActiveCell;
```

Comment: is this to imply that I should reexamine every row in the table on each event?  Since the change is still uncommitted to the dataset, wouldn't an update to the dataset overwrite the user change in the table?

Comment: You can reference the active cell for the current row during the `SheetTableUpdate` event.

Comment: If my answer sorted you out, can you please click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better using ListObject.Change event instead WorkSheet.Change event, since the arguments tell you which range ***inside*** the ListObject changes, thus avoiding every other change events from the rest of the sheet:

```
private void ListObject_Change_event(targetRange As Range, changedRanges As ListRanges)
```